# How to apply left direction for references with Persian XeLateX?

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, arabic

I am writing my thesis in Persian in Latex. Everything seems OK, but the references are not aligned properly.

I tried `\begin{flushleft}` but that didn't help. I want the references to be aligned from the left and numbers to start from the left (preferably persian numbering).

[image]

Comment: If you give a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (Minimal Working Example), you are more likely to get an answer.